# JAXB attribute with Object type throwing null pointer exception?

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to annotate a java class to create a JAXB schema with an element that has an attribute of value. The code is below:

```
    @XmlAttribute(name="value")
    public Object getSettingValue() {
        return this.settingValue;
    }

    public void setSettingValue( final Object settingValue ) {
        this.settingValue = settingValue;
    }
```

When I try to generate the schema (using Eclipse's non-Moxy implementation), I get this null pointer exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor.get(TransducedAccessor.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.AttributeProperty.<init>(AttributeProperty.java:56)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:479)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1100)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:376)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.schemagen.Main.buildJaxbContext(Main.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.schemagen.Main.generate(Main.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.schemagen.Main.execute(Main.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.schemagen.Main.main(Main.java:47)
```

When I made this an @XmlElement instead of an attribute, the schema was generated with no issues, so it must have to do with that. Any ideas?

Comment: Does you property have to be of type `Object` or can you change it to be `String`?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan We will be passing in objects of various types - either Integer, Boolean, or String (and maybe other types as we extend our application). I don't know if we could change it to String. We could possibly make a separate setter that would take a String.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I was able to change it to string and then channel it through my real method. Thanks!

Comment: I have added the approach as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` you are seeing appears to be due to a bug in the JAXB reference implementation.   You can enter a bug using the following link.

- http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB/

A similar exception does not occur when using [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as your JAXB provider.

**Workaround**

You could change the property to be of type `String` instead.  A property of type `Object` would not round trip anyways as unlike elements, attributes do not have any mechanisms to include typing information.

---

> When I made this an @XmlElement instead of an attribute, the schema
>   was generated with no issues, so it must have to do with that.

**Java Model (Root)**

Object is a valid property type when mapped to an XML element.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private Object settingValue;

    public Object getSettingValue() {
        return settingValue;
    }

    public void setSettingValue(final Object settingValue) {
        this.settingValue = settingValue;
    }

}
```

This is because the XML element can contain typing information in the form of an `xsi:type` attribute.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <settingValue 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xsi:type="xs:int">123</settingValue>
</root>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it's a bug. Xml attributes can't have complex types. See my answer.

Comment: @Puce - `String`, `Integer`, `Date` are all instances of `Object` that don't correspond to complex types in XML and can be represented as attributes in XML.  At the very least it's a bug that a NPE is thrown instead of a better exception.

Comment: Well, the NPE isn't nice, I agree, but attributes can only have types which map either to built-in types, e.g. String, Integer, Date or types which map to simple types. But not complex types. That's because XML/ XSD only allow built-in types and simple types for attributes.

Comment: @Puce - Right, so what property type do you suggest that can hold an instance of `String`, `Date`, or `Integer`?  `Object`, `Serializable`, and `Comparable` are potentials.  The JAXB RI doesn't support interfaces so that leaves `Object`.

Comment: I think you refer to xsi:type. But AFAIK this is not valid for attributes, just for elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type

Comment: Ah, OK, I understood you were argueing, that it's a bug to get an exception for `@XmlAttribute` on an Object property, since the OP was aware that it works with `@XmlElement`, but asked why it doesn't work for attributes. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute types have to map to schema built-in data types or to schema simple types.

The type Object does not match these criteria.

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_attribute.asp

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html

Comment: What you're saying is that an XmlAttriubte can be any Type as long as that type can be mapped to Xml (using JAXB), but Object cannot be mapped?

Comment: I haven't tried it in detail but as I understand it you can use types which map to build in types such as int, boolean, BigInteger, date/time/dateTime etc. or a type with a single propterty, which is annotated with @XmlValue: http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.2/jaxws/JAXWSCustomTypeMappingSimple.html